# "No parameterless constructor defined for this object" when using MVC3 with Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, dependency-injection, ninject

First off, here's the code:

Binding in the NinjectControllerFactory

```
class MrBigglesworthServices : NinjectModule
{
        public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IAuthenticationRepository>()
            .To<AuthenticationRepository>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString",
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VoiceDB"].ConnectionString
                );

        Bind<IAppRepository>()
            .To<AppRepository>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString",
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SessionStore"].ConnectionString
                );
        }
    }
```

Constructor for the Search Controller:

```
private IAppRepository appRepository;

public SearchController(IAppRepository appRepository)
{
    this.appRepository = appRepository;
}
```

Based on what I've seen with online examples, this should be enough, but for some reason, it's bringing up the error mentioned above. Any suggestions? Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you mention using a `NinjectControllerFactory` I think you are using an incorrect implementation. Consider to switch to https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3 instead. This is a widely used integration of Ninject and MVC3.